# Azure CLI v1 vs v2?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

what are some of the advantages and disadvantage of using Azure CLI v2 over Azure CLI v1?

I have searched various articles online. Sounds like Azure CLI v2 is more developer friendly, built on python and provides auto complete capabilities and works well with linux POSIX tools.

However, are there any enhancements made specifically in v2 to make it more Resilient and Fast?

Comment: The Azure CLI v2 means Azure CLI while v1 means classic CLI. V2 is more recommended and works for ARM module. See [Differences between Azure CLI products](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cli-versioning-identifiers?view=azure-cli-latest). The resource in ARM is more manageable and securable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what are some of the advantages and disadvantage of using Azure CLI v2
>   over Azure CLI v1?

You can consider them as 2 different things.

Azure classic CLI(v1) is recommended for only the classic (Azure Service Manager) deployment. And Azure classic CLI is currently only planned to have support through the end of 2018.

But Azure CLI(v2) is designed for working with the Resource Manager deployment style. And it does not support ASM/Classic mode services

> However, are there any enhancements made specifically in v2 to make it
>   more Resilient and Fast?

First, scripts are not compatible between both CLIs(v1 and v2).

Then some benefits of v2 is as following, you can also refer to this [doc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/classic_cli_migration.md#why-switch) for more details:

1.Clean outputs for common workflows, such as you can use --out table , --out json, --out tsv

2.Improved command-line productivity:

You can use [tab][tab] to lookup parameters, including resource groups and names (only supported in BASH and BASH on Windows).

Work with either Azure resource ID values (--ids) or resource group and name (-g -n).

Built in client-side query engine powered by [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/)